# Android Design: Activity only or Fragments?

Tags: android

I am working on an app for school children. Basically, there would be questions with multiple choice answers as in image below. Main requirements are:

1. Each round of a test will have 10 questions (configurable)
2. Questions with answers are loaded from an api
3. The test is timed. So each question will be visible for 10 seconds and then the next one will be presented, maybe with some animation/slide effect

My question is which of the below is the better way to do the above?

1. Have the questions and answers appear in a UI fragment while storing data in a model fragment. New questions are provided by wiring up an adaptor.. something like a ViewPager without swipes
2. Everything is one Activity. Change the question and answers by changing android:text using maybe a handler and postDelayed()

Is option 1 better as it might handle Config changes better? Or is it easier to just use option 2. Thanks..

[image: Test Question]

Comment: I think this is pretty simply done with option 2 and some inner logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to have fancy UI, go for Option 2. And architect your code using MVP approach, where the logic is in the Presenter, and the View portion handle by the Activity.

You could read more on MVP in http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/